# Drupal: why form api won't work outside the _page function?

Tags: api, drupal, forms, drupal-7

I've been reading up on the basic form api and came up with some basic workable forms... but there's this other content I'd like appended with my form, trouble is that they won't get along together.

If I put the drupal_get_form in the main _page() function, it works great ... 
If I put the drupal_get_form in a different function, it only outputs 'Array'. 
If I put the drupal_get_form results in a variable:

```
 $content = $flash;
 $content .= drupal_get_form;
```

I get an 'Array', it won't render the form. The flash appears though. (??) why is that?

I am using Drupal 7 btw,

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`drupal_get_form()` does not return a string but a so called "render array" in Drupal 7. To render it into a string, use `drupal_render()`:

```
$content .= drupal_render(drupal_get_form(...));
```

Or yo could make $content a render array too:

```
$content['flash']['#markup'] = $flash;
$content['form'] = drupal_get_form(...);
```

The advantage is that you can return render arrays in page callbacks, blocks and similar places and it will only be rendered at the end of the page request, giving other modules to change the structure of the content.